# Ktor creates an extra Java process

Tags: java, kotlin, process, ktor

I am working on a KTor server. I run the generated jar file using java -jar command. So I expect that only one Java process should run. After running for a while another Java process is being created which is bound to different port.

I checked the details of the process using ps -a [PID] and find this new Java process is "kotlin-compiler-embeddable" program.

I am wondering why this process is being created, what is use of this and is it safe to kill it.

Thanks for any pointer.

Answer (score 0):

`kotlin-compiler-embeddable` is used in scenarios when you have to package the compiler in a single jar, and no external dependencies. This is the case of Ktor.

Comment: Thank you for your answer... my question is why does it run as sparate process than the ktor app?

Comment: okay, so I did some more experiments with my system and found that this new process has nothing to do with my ktor server. This is by product of gradle build being triggered before deploying the server. 
Once I change the strategy to deploy my server i.e kill all the Java processes after building the jar file and then start the server. Everything runs smooth.